# how to add horizontal scrollbar in my table

Tags: html, css

i want to add horizontal scroll bar on my table.
i tried every thing  like overflow:scroll etc.
but it is not working on my table .
**it display another table below screen.**

i am displaying multiple tables in for loop.
but i need to display all tables in single row.but it goes down below the scree.
plz suggest me....

```
 <div class="box-body table-responsive">                
         <table style="float:left;">
         <tr>           
         <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid #ddd; "></th>      
         </tr>  
         <tr>
         <td style="float:left;">   
         <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
         <tr>       
         <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row["Edition"]; ?></th>          
         </tr>           
         <tr>       
         <td colspan="2" class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row["scheduletime"]; ?></th>        
         </tr>          
        <td>Page No</td>
        <td>Actu.Time</td>       
        </tr>                       
        <tr>                    
          <td class="scheduletime" style="text-align:center"><?php echo $i; $abc = $i; ?></td>  

  <td class="actualtime"> Save</a></td></tr>        
        </table>
        </form>
        </td></tr></table>      
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `table` is not an inline element by default.
To do so, you'd have to set its style/css to `display: inline-table`.

And to prevent the line break, you have to add to the table's parent (maybe to the body, it depends of your scenario) the property `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
body {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tb {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<table class='tb'>
    <tr>
        <td>table</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='tb'>
    <tr>
        <td>table</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='tb'>
    <tr>
        <td>table</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='tb'>
    <tr>
        <td>table</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```